# Create a function where $f(1000)=1.99$ and where $f(400000)=0.49$

Tags: functions

As per object I need to create a continuous and decreasing function with one variable where result is as above, but not only.

Function should also be easy to modify to get

$1<f(1000)<10$ and $0.1<f(400000)<1.$

From what I remember it should be a $f(1/x)$ function but...I got no result. The best match is

$$r=\frac{1}{10^{-12}x^2+0.00000334 x+0.5413},$$

but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

I think have to give you some clarifications:

this formula "should" be used to calculate price for a service according to the quantity purchased, for this reason there are some other condition to be considered:

> 1) $y$ (result/price) should reduce quickly with low values of $x$ and
>   then become more or less plain: for this purpose, straight line is not
>   acceptable
>
> 2) clearly $y$ (price) cannot be negative
>
> 3) it is strictly required that $x\cdot y(x) < (x+1)\cdot y(x+1)$ since total amount cannot reduce
>
> 4) it would be nice that once reached a level around $0.49$, $y$ should not reduce much further: just for example: $f(10.000.000)=0.40$
>
> $x\;y(x) < (x+1)\;y(x+1)$

means that the result of function $y$ multiplied by the parameter $x$ shall only increase:
in other words: since $y$ is the price and $x$ is the quantity, the total amount has to increase only: in fact it is not reasonable for example that

> $f(10000)=1.5\;\;\; and\;\;\; f(20000)=0.6$

since this means that for 10,000 pieces I will pay 15,000.00 and that for 20.000 pieces will pay only 12,000.00

Thanks for your time!

joe

Comment: What's wrong with a straight line?

Comment: What about a function $f$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are constant coefficients) such that $f(1000)=1.99$ and $f(400000)=0.49$...?

Comment: This question needs clarification.  As you see, every commenter is saying the same thing...straight line interpolation is simple, clean, and passes every test you mentioned.  I expect you left off some constraints (maybe you want your function to stay positive for all values?).

Comment: Note:  I made some edits which I believe reflect your intent but if, instead, I introduced errors please correct them back.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: After the question was updated this answer no longer works. Lulu seems to have a good answer that meets the additional criteria.

Why not just a straight line that passes through those two points?

$f(x) = mx+b$, such that $f(1000)=1.99$ and $f(400000)=0.49$. This easily generalizes to the more general requirement as well.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't understand the constraints.  What does "$yx<y(x+1)$" mean? I don't think it means $y(x)<y(x+1)$ since you previously specified that the function should be decreasing.

Just to take a stab at it, why not stick with your first guess and adapt $\frac 1x$?  Specifically, look at $$f(x) = \frac ax+b$$
Using your data we easily specify the parameters and get:
$$f(x) = \frac {1503.7594}{x}+.4862406$$
This certainly passes your limit test (the function decays slowly to .486, just below the upper value you mentioned).

I see from your comments that the constraint I didn't understand means that you require $xf(x)<(x+1)f(x+1)$.  I note that for functions of my form we have:$$xf(x)=a+bx$$ and as $bx<b(x+1)$, so long as $b$ is positive, my function passes that test as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assume

$y=f(x)=ae^{-bx},\ a,b>0$

Or equivalently

$log(y)=log(a)-bx$

Substituting the numerical data for x and y and solving the associated linear system yields:

$f(x)=1.997002e^{-0.351249\times10^{-5}x}$